# How to decode a webpage into UTF8 regardless of its encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, html

I'm using `WebClient.DownloadFile` in C# to download web pages. They download fine, but the encoding is often ambiguous (no BOM present). The Mozilla Universal Charset Detector ([port 1](https://github.com/superstrom/chardetsharp), [port 2](https://github.com/errepi/ude)) provides a system to detect the encoding of plaintext files using heuristics and [this](http://www.architectshack.com/TextFileEncodingDetector.ashx) provides an even simpler method that recognizes fewer encodings.

So firstly, are HTML web pages even encoded in strange encodings like Shift-JIS and EUC-KR? If not, then a faster detection method can be used that assumes something is ASCII/ANSI or UTF8.

Secondly, even after detecting the encoding, how does one go about decoding the `byte[]` of the file into an appropriate UTF8 string? And after doing some string processing, can I save the file back to disk with a UTF8 BOM? Or would I have to add extra tags like `<meta charset="utf-8"..">` into the HTML file as well?

Comment: I had the same problem. The declared encoding sometimes is completely wrong (not to mention that it is declared in the text of the web page, which needs to be decoded first http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp), the BOM is almost always missing. I think heuristics is the only reasonable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web page's character set *should* be described by the [content-type reponse header, especially the `charset` attribute](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index), but it usually isn't. Sometimes there's an `<meta http-equiv="content-type" />`, but when even that is lacking, all bets are off and you need to go detect the actual encoding.

So you seem to be on the right way forward.

> are HTML web pages even encoded in strange encodings

That depends on the pages you're requesting.

> how does one go about decoding the byte[] of the file into an appropriate UTF8 string?

You don't want to. Strings in .NET are all encoded as UTF-16 internally, and all utility functions work with that format.

So `string content = Encoding.GetEncoding(yourDetectedEncoding).GetString(contentBytes)` will do just fine.

Then you can write this UTF-16 encoded `content` string back into an UTF-8 encoded file, with BOM:

```
File.WriteAllText(path, content, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: By `appropriate UTF8 string?` I meant the string format that C# needs. So you, UTF-16.

Comment: @Harsh yes, so then that's UTF-16.